# javascript automatic create button with individuell onclick event

Tags: javascript

i create a lot of listboxes and buttons with javascript.
each button should access a list box. The automatic create in a loop is not a problem. but the click event gives me problems.
normally i would:

```
 var el = document.getElementById ('AButton');
 el.onclick = DoFunction;
```

call this only with automatically created button?
How can I automatically create the DoFunction individually, so that it makes something individual for each button? So is it always the same only with individual controls?

```
function DoFunction(selectbox)
{
    var i;
    for(i=selectbox.options.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        selectbox.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use event bubbling feature. Just create a onclick function on parent and start reading the click of individual button. Here you can use event.target.value to identify the listbox from where action is treiggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```js
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  var btnTwo = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  
  btnTwo.innerHTML = "button";
  div.appendChild(btnTwo);
})
```

```html
<button id="btn">click</button>
<div id="div"></div>
```